# Changing data type "Varchar" to "TimeStamp" in PostgreSQL

Tags: types, timestamp, varchar, sqldatatypes

My data-set contains a column which includes date and time in "varchar" data-type as following:

04/23/2009  11:34:01

The data-type of the aforementioned column is varchar, I wanted to ask how I can change the data type to "timestamp".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add a new NULLable column of the target type to the table.

You can than attempt to fill the column data base on naieve parsing of the data.

You can then run a SELECT to compare the original date string to the new date string, but also use an output formatter function so the strings should be indentical.  Then ask SQL to compare both value by using HAVING clause.

Once you have a solution to be able to convert the existing data.

You should work on the change of strategy.  This will possibly require changes to software.  This maybe done by first ensure all data that INSERT, UPDATE will save the data in BOTH columns.

You then run your conversion procedure on all existing data.

At this point in time all change to the DB should maintain both old column and new column consistently.  Maybe you need to audit/run system for a while to make sure everything is caught, since you can now re-run your comparison/verification step at any time.

Then you can work on SELECT usage cases.  Then finally actually remove the VARCHAR column.

The point of all this is a controlled step by step procedure where there is rollback option and testing in between each change.